# What does !! (double exclamation point) mean?

Tags: perl, operators, boolean, negation

In the code below, from a [blog post by Alias](http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_Alias/journal/39126.html), I noticed the use of the double exclamation mark `!!`. I was wondering what it meant and where I could go in the future to find explanations for Perl syntax like this. (Yes, I already searched for `!!` at [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)).

```
package Foo;
 
use vars qw{$DEBUG};
BEGIN {
    $DEBUG = 0 unless defined $DEBUG;
}
use constant DEBUG => !! $DEBUG;
 
sub foo {
    debug('In sub foo') if DEBUG;
 
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all of your answers.

Here is something else I just found that is related [The List Squash Operator `x!!`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=564792)

Comment: If you think `!!` is a fun operator, try out the `-->` operator in a for loop. :)

Comment: Ether, can you post a link to the --> operator? I don't know how to find it on google.

Comment: @Geo: here you go (you'll laugh; don't hate me): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't aware C had lolcat operators :)

Comment: javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT#double_not_!!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is just two `!` boolean not operators sitting next to each other.

The reason to use this idiom is to make sure that you receive a `1` or a `0`. Actually it returns an empty string which numifys to 0. It's usually only used in numeric, or boolean context though.

You will often see this in [Code Golf](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions+code-golf+perl) competitions, because it is shorter than using the ternary `? :` operator with `1` and `0` <sub>(`$test ? 1 : 0`)</sub>.

```
!! undef  == 0
!! 0      == 0
!! 1      == 1
!! $obj   == 1
!! 100    == 1

undef ? 1 : 0  == 0
0     ? 1 : 0  == 0
1     ? 1 : 0  == 1
$obj  ? 1 : 0  == 1
100   ? 1 : 0  == 1
```

Comment: I actually often use `!!!!` in my code, because `!!` confuses vim's syntax highlighting and another `!!` will restore it!

Comment: @Ether: *Obviously*, you need to use emacs. :)

Comment: It produces 1 or the canonical false value, not 0.  This is 0 in numeric context but the empty string in string context.  To get 0 or 1, use the `1-!` operator :)

Comment: @Brad: -1 to get your attention on ysth's comment, will revoke upon fix.

Comment: Speaking as the guy that wrote the same code, it's there because I want anything odd in that variable normalised away at compile time. It's just a sort of quality protection mechanism.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your answer. I just started reading a draft of chromatic's new book and I like how he says that `!!` "forces boelean context".

Answer (score 12):

not-not.

It converts the value to a boolean (or as close as Perl gets to such a thing).

Comment: It's also a common idiom in other languages too like Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Because three other answers claim that the range is "0" or "1", I just thought I'd mention that booleans in Perl (as returned by operators like `==`, `not`, and so on) are `undef` and `1`, not `0` and `1`.

Comment: This is not correct.  When an operator has to generate a false value, it uses a magic value that evaluates as the empty string in string context or 0 in numeric context.  (The exceptions are operators like `and` and `or`, which simply return the operand that caused them to return false.)  (See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood)

Comment: undef is also a magic value that evaluates as '' in string context and 0 in numeric context -- the only difference is that when warnings are enabled, using undef for its string or numeric value is apt to produce a warning, while 'the false value' does no such thing ;)

Comment: @hobbs: Well, another difference is that `defined(undef)` is false, but `defined(1==2)` is true.

Comment: Actually it returns a zero length string.

Comment: +1 You obviously had an influence on the other answers. Brad modified his answer after yours. Also, at least one of those you mentioned ended up deleting his or her answer as well.

Comment: @molecules Actually I modified my answer based on the comment from [ysth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth).