# Is there a simple way to test if a Moose attribute is read-only?

Tags: perl, testing, tdd, attributes, moose

I currently use a block `eval` to test that I've set an attribute as read-only. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Example from working code:

```
#Test that sample_for is ready only
eval { $snp_obj->sample_for('t/sample_manifest2.txt');};
like($@, qr/read-only/xms, "'sample_for' is read-only");
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to friedo, Ether, and Robert P for their answers and to Ether, Robert P, and jrockway for their comments.

I like how Ether's answer ensures that `$is_read_only` is only a true or false value (i.e. but never a coderef) by negating it with a `!`. [Double negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168406/what-does-double-exclamation-point-mean) also provides that. Thus, you can use `$is_read_only` in an `is()` function, without it printing out the coderef.

See Robert P's answer below for the most complete answer. Everyone has been very helpful and built on each other's answers and comments. Overall, I think he's helped me the most, hence his is now marked the accepted answer. Again, thanks to Ether, Robert P, friedo, and jrockway.

In case you might be wondering, as I did at first, here is documentation about the difference between `get_attribute` and `find_attribute_by_name` ([from Class::MOP::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::MOP::Class)):

```
$metaclass->get_attribute($attribute_name)

    This will return a Class::MOP::Attribute for the specified $attribute_name. If the 
    class does not have the specified attribute, it returns undef.

    NOTE that get_attribute does not search superclasses, for that you need to use
    find_attribute_by_name.
```

Comment: That would be better written as `ok($snp_obj->meta->get_attribute('sample_for')->get_write_method(), "'sample_for' is read-only");` -- on test failure, `is()` prints the 2nd argument (which would be a coderef).. not to mention you have the 1st and 2nd arguments reversed: `is($has, $expected, $test_name)`.

Comment: If your @attribute_names array is carefully constructed, you should be fine; but if the attribute doesn't exist you'll explode :)

Comment: +1 for noting how to locate attribute in superclass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, an attribute does not need to have a read or a write method.  *Most* of the time it will, but not always.  An example (graciously stolen from [jrockway's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562767/is-there-a-simple-way-to-test-if-a-moose-attribute-is-read-only/2562806#2562806)) is below:

```
has foo => ( 
    isa => 'ArrayRef', 
    traits => ['Array'], 
    handles => { add_foo => 'push', get_foo => 'pop' }
)
```

This attribute will exist, but not have standard readers and writers.

So to test in every situation that an attribute has been defined as `is => 'RO'`, you need to check both the write and the read method.  You could do it with this subroutine:

```
# returns the read method if it exists, or undef otherwise.
sub attribute_is_read_only {
    my ($obj, $attribute_name) = @_;
    my $attribute = $obj->meta->get_attribute($attribute_name);

    return unless defined $attribute;
    return (! $attribute->get_write_method() && $attribute->get_read_method());
}
```

Alternatively, you could add a double negation before the last `return` to boolify the return value:

```
return !! (! $attribute->get_write_method() && $attribute->get_read_method());
```

Answer (score 5):

As documented in [Class::MOP::Attribute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Class::MOP::Attribute#Informational):

```
my $attr = $this->meta->find_attribute_by_name($attr_name);
my $is_read_only = ! $attr->get_write_method();
```

`$attr->get_write_method()` will get the writer method (either one you created or one that was generated), or undef if there isn't one.

Comment: Thanks! Knowing that it returns `undef` allows for a one line test (I tried posting it here, but it did not look very pretty).

Comment: Well, actually... That tests if it has a write method.  That doesn't test if it has a read method though.  It doesn't have to have either, technically.  It's not a very useful attribute if it doesn't, but you can have it!

Comment: @Robert: Yes, strictly speaking it checks that the attribute is "not writeable" (not isa => 'rw'), which is not quite the same as "readonly" (isa => 'ro').

Comment: Attributes without readers are plenty useful.  Consider the case of `has foo => ( isa => 'ArrayRef', traits => ['Array'], handles => { add_foo => 'push', get_foo => 'pop' })`.  No need for a reader!

Comment: @jrockway that's an excellent example of an attribute without readers or writers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get this from the object's metaclass:

```
unless ( $snp_obj->meta->get_attribute( 'sample_for' )->get_write_method ) { 
    # no write method, so it's read-only
}
```

See [Class::MOP::Attribute](http://search.cpan.org/~stevan/Class-MOP/lib/Class/MOP/Attribute.pm) for more.