# What does the double exclamation !! operator mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript)
>   [What does !! (double exclamation point) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168406/what-does-double-exclamation-point-mean)

I am going through some custom JavaScript code at my workplace and I am not able to understand the following construct.

```
var myThemeKey = (!!$('row') && $('row').hasClassName('green-theme')) ? 'green' : 'white';
```

I understand everything on the above line except `!!` operator. I assume that it is a `NOT` operator and `NOT` of `NOT` is the original value but why would someone do a `NOT` of `NOT`?

Can someone please help me understand what is happening on the above line of code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: Repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-operator-in-javascript

Comment: The short answer is that it converts the value to boolean - so if it has non-zero it's true, else false.

Comment: @stirfries - Welcome to stackoverflow. This question has already been asked before, so your question will probably be closed. When it does just follow the links to the first time the question was asked and you should find the info you're looking for.

Comment: In the future, do not start titles with "Please help me understand..." This gives only very bad results in the possible duplicate search list while you're typing in the question. Just make it a clear, concrete and to-the-point question. Then you'll get results like as right now in the "Related" section on the right column (with among others some duplicate questions with the answers you're looking for ;) ).

Comment: @Richard JP Le Guen - Thanks...I appreciate the directions.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks for the tips...I will follow the same in the future.

Answer (score 272):

The `!!` ensures the resulting type is a boolean (true or false).

`javascript:alert("foo")` --> `foo`

`javascript:alert(!"foo")` --> `false`

`javascript:alert(!!"foo")` --> `true`

`javascript:alert(!!"")` --> `false`

`javascript:alert(!!"0")` --> `true`

`javascript:alert(!!null)` --> `false`

They do this to make sure `$('row')` isn't null.

It's shorter to type than `$('row') != null ? true : false`.

Comment: I'd just like to add that this is a double negation: `!` returns `true` if the object is *null*, *undefined* or an empty string and `false` otherwise. If you negate it again you get `true` for values that exist and `false` for the ones that do not.

Comment: Also !!NaN return false

Comment: could you explain, how is a string a boolean?  There's some further explanation there.  What does typescript consider to be true in terms of a string?

Comment: You wouldn't ever need `$('row') != null ? true : false` even if you didn't use `!!`.  You could just use `$('row') != null`, which is itself a boolean.  There is no need to convert a boolean to a boolean.  Once it is shortened in that manner, it actually seems clearer to me to use `!= null` than `!!` and not so much longer.