# Use of double negation (!!) 

Tags: perl, operators, boolean

Okay so I came across a code which looks like

```
@documents_names = sort {
         !!$deleted_documents_names{$a} == !!$deleted_documents_names{$b}
          ? uc($a) cmp uc($b)
          : !!$deleted_documents_names{$a}
          cmp !!$deleted_documents_names{$b}
         } @documents_names;
```

It's the first time I'm seeing the use of double negation. What's the use of it? When would a person use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168406/what-does-double-exclamation-point-mean

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It converts non-boolean types to boolean (`dualvar(0,"")` or `1`).

It is a shortcut way of doing this, instead of trying to cast it explicitly (which may take more characters). The `!` operator negates the truthness of its argument. Hence, two of them are used.

Many object types are "truthy", and others are "falsey".

- The only false values are `0`, `undef`, `""`, `"0"` and some overloaded objects.
- Examples of true values are `1`, `"asdf"`, and all other values.

Comment: Your answer + http://stackoverflow.com/a/2168511/257635 = Satisfaction! :P

Comment: `'null'` would evaluate to true in Perl. Did you mean `undef`?

Comment: this is not my native language... (I mean in terms of programming languages)

Comment: @amon : What about the empty list `()`?

Comment: BTW, `!!` does not produce the empty string exactly.  Perl's canonical false value is an empty string in string context, but 0 in numeric context (without any warning about a non-numeric value, which a normal empty string would generate in numeric context).

Comment: It's impossible to pass an empty list to a boolean test, so empty lists are neither true nor false. `()` (an operator that returns undef in scalar context)  should no more be in the list than `-f "nonexistant"` (an operator that returns undef). Values are true or false, not operators.

Comment: I like using `!!0` as a shorthand for "that special empty string that Perl's standard relational and equality operators produce".   As discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541833/what-values-should-a-boolean-function-in-perl-return, you cannot refactor, i.e. you cannot get exactly the same behavior, `return $a<$b` into `if($a<$b){return 1} else{return 0}`, but you can if you do `return !!0`.

Answer (score 10):

That is a lot of funk for a `sort` block!

It's essentially a two-level sort :

1. ascii-betical
2. deleted files first, then undeleted

So one could rewrite it as (untested):

```
@documents = sort {  exists $deleted_documents_names{$a} # same effect as '!!'
                       <=> 
                     exists $deleted_documents_names{$b}
                  ||
                     uc( $a ) cmp uc( $b )
                  }
             @documents;
```

Comment: That's not completely right since `<=>` is an operator for numbers. You should use `cmp` instead to work with the alphabetical comparison of strings. Nice sort clarification though. :)

Comment: @memowe : Yeah, thanks for that.. like I said I hadn't tested it :)