# Double "!!" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does !! mean in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524658/what-does-mean-in-ruby)
>   [Ruby, !! operator (a/k/a the double-bang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994033/ruby-operator-a-k-a-the-double-bang)

Sometimes I see a Ruby code like this

```
def sent?
  !!@sent_at
end
```

It seems to be not logical. Is it necessary to use here double `!`? As far as I'm concerned, it might be just

```
def sent?
  @sent_at
end
```

UPDATE: then what is the difference between these

```
def sent?
  !!@sent_at
end

def sent?
  @sent_at.nil?
end

def sent?
  @sent_at == nil
end
```

Comment: Hey man I updated my answer. (plz delete this reply after seeing it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Ruby guy, but I guess it's for converting @sent_at to a boolean.

UPDATE: Ah ha I saw your update. Notice that `false` and `nil` are different; `false.nil? == false`, while `nil.nil? == true`. In ruby only `false` and `nil` will be treated as "false"; even an empty string, `''`, is evaluated as `true` (it is `False` in python).

Comment: Yes you are right. Nice programmer instinct.

Answer (score 2):

`Double Bang` is use to convert anything into a boolean in Ruby.

http://rubyquicktips.com/post/583755021/convert-anything-to-boolean

Answer (score 1):

It forces a truthy-value to true and a falsy-value to false. In Ruby the [**only** falsy-values are nil and false](http://raflabs.com/blogs/silence-is-foo/2010/08/12/nil-true-false-ruby/) and everything other value is a truthy-value.

```
!falsyExpr   # given -> true
!true        # and -> false
!!falsyExpr  # then -> true -> false

!truthyExpr  # given -> false
!false       # and -> true
!!truthyExpr # then -> false -> true
```

The reason to use `!!expr` over `expr`, when returned from a method like this, is that the `!!expr` form *only* yields true or false. This avoids leaking details, avoids accidental strong-references, reduces confusion when debugging, prevents cases of false/nil confusion, etc. It is also shorter than `expr ? true : false`, which has identical semantics.

The forms `expr == nil` and `expr.nil?` *only evaluate to true when `expr` evaluates to nil*. They are both false if `expr` evaluates to any other value, *including false*. This sets them apart from the `!expr` which evaluates to true for both *false and nil* values.

Of course the all of the above is *expected behavior*. Due to the open nature of Ruby and operator overloading it is possible (and very misguided) to create new methods that change this expected behavior (barring some implementation optimization quirks).

Answer (score 1):

Using `!!` makes sure either `true` or `false` is returned. So, yes, it makes sense.

```
@sent_at = 'Foo'
!!@sent_at # => true

@sent_at = nil
!!@sent_at # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

It converts non-boolean types to boolean (`true` or `false`).

It is a shortcut way of doing this, instead of trying to cast it explicitly (which may take more characters). The ! operator negates the truthness of its argument. Hence, two of them are used.

Also see [Use of double negation (!!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278997/use-of-double-negation)  for perl (or for most other languages).