# Is there a way to convert an integer to 1 if it is >= 1 without using any relational operator?

Tags: c, math, boolean, logical-operators, simd

In my program, I have a statement like the following, inside a loop.

```
y = (x >= 1)? 0:1;
```

However, I want to avoid using any relational operator, because I want to use SIMD instructions, and am not sure if relational operators work well with SIMD.

I want something like the following.

```
a = some_operation(x) // a will be either 1 or 0
y = 1 - a
```

Where `some_operation` would convert any number equal or greater than 1 to 1, and keep 0 to 0. So, my question is, is there any `some_operation` that would achieve my purpose?

Comment: Actually, SSE has a several `max`/`min` instructions, so if you are sure that `x` cannot be between 0 and 1 something like `x = x>1?1:x;` should translate to efficient code using `maxpd` or something like that.

Comment: If you're only trying to avoid using `>`, go the other way around using `==`. `y = (x == 0 ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: Are you working on a signed or unsigned variable?

Comment: I feel like we are talking different languages. It doesn't matter if you avoid language constructs where the `>` token appears or where there's no explicit `if` or `?`, the point is if it can be translated to branchless SIMD instructions.

Comment: I want to avoid using any realtional operator.

Comment: That is some micro-optimization (even a nano-optimization) which you really should leave to your compiler.

Comment: This `y = (x > 1)? 0:1;` and the question's title are somehow not in line ...

Comment: [What does !!(x) mean in C (esp. the Linux kernel)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2527086/995714), [What does !! (double exclamation point) mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2168406/995714), [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/995714)

Comment: The title says `>= 1`, but the code in the question says `> 1`. Which is it?

Comment: `(x >= 1)? 0:1;` evaluates to `0` for all `i >= 1`. The title say the opposite.

Comment: I don’t know the first thing about C, but doesn’t the ‘old-fashioned’ way of doing this by doing `y = (int) (bool) x` avoid relational operators? Or can you not do that at all in C?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: This would return 1 for negative values as well.

Comment: @alk Ah yes, of course it will. Brain fart!

Comment: This is a silly question. You've been given two perfectly good SIMD suggestions (vectorizing `min(x, 1)` or `x > 0`) which you've dismissed with no underlying reason, instead accepting an answer which answers the letter but not the spirit of your request.

Comment: To be clear, negative number should become 0 or 1 or don't care?  Is `x` signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define INT_BITS (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int))

int make_zero_or_one(int x) {
   return 1 - (((x-1) >> (INT_BITS-1)) & 1);
}
```

Like the other answers, this relies upon the MSB being the sign bit in ints. The function returns 0 for all ints <= 0 and 1 otherwise. The function will fail if `x-1` overflows.

This implementation has no branches in compiled code.

Comment: This invokes UB for `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @alk yes, that's true, but for most practical situations, reaching the limits of integer representations normally brings up other issues.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to convert an integer to 1 if it is >= 1 without using any relational operator?

For *unsigned* integers you can simply do:

```
unsigned int i = 42; // ... or any other value > 0.
unsigned int j = !!i; // j is 1 here.

i = 0;
j = !!i; // j is 0 here.
```

---

Update:

For *signed* integers you can do

```
int i = ...
int j = !!(i * !((1 << ((CHAR_BITS * sizeof i) - 1)) & i));
```

The above line results in

- `0` for any `i < 1`
- `1` for any `i >= 1`

Comment: `!!x` is just a complicated way to write `x?1:0`; it doesn't change a thing from the compiler perspective. The signed version also generates horrible code. https://godbolt.org/g/Kg69U6

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I never claimed this to be elegant. Still whether `!!x` or `x?1:0` is more or less complicated is a matter of how you look at it,

Comment: Whatever, the point is that it doesn't change the codegen. Again: a conditional remains a conditional even if you hide it under different syntax.

Comment: This is obviously way more complicated than `>=` which all mainstream SIMD ISAs do support.  (x86 only for signed types directly; unsigned compare takes a range shift until AVX-512).    But yeah, signed is very complicated to do "manually", unlike hardware compares that work like OF != SF (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc).  If not for the possibility of signed overflow (e.g. from INT_MIN), a logical right shift on `i - 1`.  e.g. `(i - 1U) >> 31` (or `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(i)-1`) would work to get the sign bit as a 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use two's complement you can do this.
(The other answer to use !!x may or may not be what you are looking for, depending on the computer's instruction set and why you want to avoid relational operators)

```
int x = 42; // or any integer

int test = x-1;
if(test & 1 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int) -1))
{
   // integer negative or zero
}
else
{
   // integer positive
}
```

Comment: This invokes UB for `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Actually for INT_MIN. But even x = -x is UB for that, generally we assume that integers represent something and are in range.

Comment: Sure `INT_MIN`...- sry.

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that this answer explicitly contradicts your question, but there are SIMD comparisons on all common SIMD architectures (at least all I know).

For SSE2 and `int32` parameters there is `pcmpgtd` (intrinsic: `_mm_cmpgt_epi32`), assuming you have 4 integers in `__m128i x`, you can write

```
__m128i result = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(x, _mm_setzero_si128())
```

To get `-1` (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF`) for every `x>0` (i.e. `x>=1`) and `0` otherwise. If you need `1` instead of `-1` just write

```
__m128i y =  _mm_sub_epi32(_mm_setzero_si128(), result);
```

Comment: Instead of sub-from-zero, `_mm_srli_epi32(v, 31)` is also good, often fewer instructions.  But if you want to do something like count the true cases, `matches = _mm_sub_epi32( matches, cmp_result)` subtracts 0 or minus-1, i.e. increments according to the compare result.  Actually creating a `1` in each SIMD element wastes instructions in most cases.

Comment: Also, compilers know how to auto-vectorize, so it's not necessary to use intrinsics, and the premise of the question is false (that `==` or `<=` are a problem).  *branching* on a compare could be a problem if it's not easy for the compiler to if-convert into branchless, but branchless scalar code using a compare result is usually 100% fine.  e.g. [Why is processing an unsorted array the same speed as processing a sorted array with modern x86-64 clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66521344) shows clang vectorizing the famous `if (data[c] >= 128)  sum += data[c];`

Comment: So other than silly computer tricks, the real answer to the question is this and that compilers can auto-vectorize `==` and `<=` / `>`.  Any of the other answers, except compares in disguise like `!!x`, will typically compile to slower code.

Answer (score 0):

int any_number_to_one = 0 || any_expression

Depends a bit on the compiler, but hey ;-)

Comment: What do you use for `any_expression` to get a non-zero for `x>=1` but a zero for `x<1`?  The OP (misguidedly) wants to avoid `>=`, so `0 || (x>=1)` wouldn't work.  And `0 || (x-1)` doesn't work at all, it's non-zero for negative, and has signed-integer overflow for `INT_MIN`.  Oh, maybe you were thinking for unsigned `x`, so `x >= 1` is equivalent to `x != 0`, booleanizing like `!!x` or your `0 || x`?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with C or using SIMD instructions, but if x is a positive integer,can't you just do this?

```
y = (x == 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I want to avoid any relational operator.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't see that stipulation. Perhaps the double not operation given by @alk?

Answer (score -2):

Use this:  `y= 1/(1+e^(-10000*(x-0.995)))`

This will give `y = 0 for x <= 0.99`   and `y=1 for x>= 1`

I don't know what SIMD is and there could very well be a better way to do this. But I figured, if you don't want to use a condition you can use a sigmoid function that returns a 0 or a 1 according to your criteria. This function would be your `some_operation(x)` .Note that this function will only work for numbers with 2 decimals. That is, an input of 0.99 will return 0 but an input of 0.999 will return 1. Make sure you round your number **down** to the nearest 2-decimal number before doing the calculation.

I will go through step by step of my thought process below if anyone is interested:

If you want to use a function, and not a logical condition it would have to be continuous which by definition would mean that som of the values would not fit the criteria. But if those values were within a very narrow range, and your steps between numbers were bigger than that narrow range it would work.

So you could use a sigmoid function. (input it into wolfram alpha so see each change)

```
  y =  1/(1+e^(-x))
```

And shift it one step to the right so it's centered around 1 instead of zero.

```
  y = 1/(1+e^(-(x-1)))
```

Then you can increase the slope of the function by increasing the weight.

```
  y= 1/(1+e^(-10000*(x-1)))
```

Now the slope is really, really steep. 
But we still get y = 0.5 if we input x=1.  So we need to shift the sigmoid a bit to the left.

```
y= 1/(1+e^(-10000*(x-0.995)))
```

Now we will get y= 0 if x <= 0.99 and y=1 if x >= 1.
If you want to use a finer resolution you would have to adjust the weight (10000 in this case) and the center point (0.995 in this case). 
I just checked the calculation in wolfram alpha and iterated what works. You can use a weight as low as 4000 if you are using only 2 decimals.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but this is how I would solve it.

Comment: In C, `^` is bitwise xor, which doesn't work on `double`s.  Even if this did work, division and exponential would be slower than just doing scalar integer compares.  This answer is totally on the wrong track for performance optimization, even if you replaced `e^(stuff)` with `exp(stuff)` library function calls.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree. But the question didn't mention anything about performance.

Comment: The wrote *because I want to use SIMD instructions,* - Performance is the reason SIMD exists.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data .  If you didn't / don't know what SIMD is and didn't look it up, then you wouldn't have know when you wrote this.  But it is in fact true that wanting to vectorize with SIMD (or making your code auto-vectorization friendly) is about performance.