# Branchless calculation for multiplying by the complement of a fraction with a flag

Tags: math, optimization, branchless

I'm writing a program that is doing some geometric calculations and I have a certain calculation where I need to multiply either by a fraction `a` or by `1-a` given the value of a certain flag. Here's some pseudocode to help illustrate.

```
switch b
    case 0:
        return w*a
    case 1:
        return w*(1-a)
```

(In context this isn't an entire function, it's just done inlined obviously, but this is the only context required for the question)

I'm curious if there is a way to calculate this value using the value of the flag `b` with basic arithmetic operations etc for a branchless approach. The best I've come up with so far is `!b*w*a + b*w*(1-a)`, but that feels like a cop-out lol.

My next best approach was `w*abs(a-b)`, but this would require an `abs` function that also meets the specification.

This isn't very performance critical and even if it was I'm sure my 'cop-out' would suffice, but I'm asking more as a curiosity :)

Comment: Before you try too hard to micro optimise the C code here take a look at the generated assembler code. It wouldn't surprise me if it worked out both and then used CMOV to put the right value into the result register. if (b) seems to optimise better for me (than switch (b) ). YMMV See for example [CMOV vs branch prediction fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131096/why-is-a-conditional-move-not-vulnerable-to-branch-prediction-failure)

Comment: Yeah like I said, the branch would probably be the best actual option. I'm mainly asking this to get more experience with branchless stuff and bit-twiddling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming flag `b` is always equal to exactly 0 or 1, and cannot be equal to other values:

```
return w * (b * a + (1 - b) * (1 - a))
```

Only one of `b` and `1-b` will be nonzero, so only one of the terms in the sum will be nonzero.

To force `b` to be equal to 0 or 1, you can use double negation `!!`:

```
b = !!b
return w * (b * a + (1 - b) * (1 - a))
```

Or write `b == 0` and `b != 0` explicitly:

```
return w * ((b != 0) * a + (b == 0) * (1 - a))
```

For discussion about whether `b = !!b` is preferable to alternatives `b = b?1:0` or `b = b != 0`, see [this answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43693924/3080723).

Comment: return w*(2*a*b + 1 - a - b); has fewer proper multiplications, but the optimiser might do this anyway.

Comment: `w*(2*a*b+1-a-b)` produces fewer instructions, at least on -O2 where I tested it. `w*(b*a+(1-b)*(1-a))` produces nearly identical instructions to the 'cop-out' I included in my question